# Errors in loading IGraphM

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages, broken-code

I have been using `IGraphM` without any problem until today. My `Codes` using `IGraphM` started to give me the following errors and I do not know why. Maybe someone knows why and how to solve it.

```
MessageName::messg: IGraphM`LTemplate`Classes`IGlobal::usage cannot be  set to StringTemplate[class ``: ``][IGlobal,    StringTemplate[`` ``(``)][Void, init, ]
StringTemplate[`` ``(``)][Void, seedRandom, Integer]
StringTemplate[`` ``(``)][UTF8String, version, ]
StringTemplate[`` ``(``)][UTF8String, compilationDate, ]
StringTemplate[`` ``(``)][Boolean, infOrNanQ, Constant List<Real, _>]
StringTemplate[`` ``(``)][Boolean,\[Ellipsis] t List<Real, 2>]
StringTemplate[`` ``(``)][List<Complex, 1>, takeUpperComplex, Constant List<Complex, 2>]
StringTemplate[`` ``(``)][List<Integer, 2>, upperIndexPairPositions, Constant List<Integer, 2>, Integer]
StringTemplate[`` ``(``)][List<Integer, 2>, lowerIndexPairPositions, Constant List<Integer, 2>, Integer]]. It must be set to a string.
```

Comment: Can you provide a MWE, not just the error messages?

Comment: @Rohit Namjoshi:  There is no example because I just want to recall the code  ``<< IGraphM`` and ``<< BoolEval``. The messages referred to come when I invoke the above commands.

Comment: @Rohit Namjoshi: It is to my surprise that after restarting my computer, the error messages referred disappeared. The problem might be that internal processing of my computer has messed up due to heavy computations. Now I have no problem, and all is working as expected.